# appending two variables in php having `$` symbol in the appending string

Tags: php, concatenation

can I know how to create following types of string using loop.

```
$row[$opt1val]
$row[$opt2val]
$row[$opt3val]
$row[$opt4val]
//...
```

In general I create like this
`

```
foreach($myArray as $someVar => $value){
    $i++;
    ${"opt".$i."val"} = $value;
}
```

But to how to create this `$row[$opt1val] kind of strings so the string should behave as variable.

I tried but failed as I might not be doing at `$` symbol, please bear with me as I am one day old with php

Comment: `${"opt".$i."val"}` creates the variables `$opt1val` `$opt2val` .. etc. What is your question?

Comment: hi Halcyon, I need the whole string formed inside `$row[ ]` i.e. `$row[$opt1val]`, as i am creating and assigning the variables dynamically and also using them for retrieving data from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [variable variable name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)s:

```
$varName = 'row' . $i . 'val';
$row[ $$varName ];
```

Comment: Hey marekful, thanks for the answer, it saved lots of my precious time :)

Answer (score 0):

Use variable of variables -

```
$opt1val = '1';
$opt2val = '2';

for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
   $val = 'opt'.$i.'val';
   echo $$val. " - ";
}
```

in your case it would be -

```
$val= 'opt' . $i . 'val';
$row[ $$val];
```